# How to declare the progressIndicator without a parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, progress-bar

Following is the progress indicator:

```
var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>((int i) =>
            { 
                progressBar.PerformStep();
            });
```

Following is the async method signature that updates the progress bar.

```
private async Task AsyncMtdCAll(int val, IProgress<int> progress)
        {
         .....    
         .....
         progress.Report(1); 
        }
```

I am forced to write `new Progress<int>((int i) =>` when declaring the progressIndicator. Otherwise the code doesn't build. Hence later on, I have to pass dummy value 1 into the call `progress.Report(1);`.

Is there any way to declare the progressIndicator without a parameter?

Comment: You could add an extension method on IProgress<T> that doesn't require the param.

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/anfAjU

Comment: @Fildor - I do not want to pass anything into the progress parameters - can this be done? Example: `progress.Report();`

Comment: Have a look into the fiddle, I linked.

Comment: You can also change `= new Progress<int>(_=> progressBar1.PerformStep());` (+ what Fildor suggested).